# How login information is cached?

Tags: forms-authentication, cache

I have created a custom authentication provider to allow
user to access Sharepoint with FBA. The web application zone I'm accessing allows both Windows Authentication and FBA.

I see that if one user is logged in and I delete browser history (cookies included) and close the browser, the users enters the site without being asked how they want to be authenticated.

Can anyone explain how this authentication caching process works and if I can disable it?